# Changing Netlify DNS results in SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN "Your connection is not private"

Tags: dns, netlify

Changing Netlify DNS results in SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN "Your connection is not private" in Chrome

This was after the domain configuration was set (i.e. a change of settings)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to renew certificate after changing the domain information (which at this time was not specified in the docs)

Options found under:
Site settings > Domain management > HTTPS > Renew Certificate
[image: Renew Certificate]